# Prevent query rewriting in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I have a column TypeCode varchar(20) that has values like '1', '2', '3', 'FOO', 'BAR'. I need to find the maximum integer which is less than the value of parameter. Something like this:

```
select max(TypeCode) TypeCode
    from table1 a
    left join table2 b on b.table1id = a.id
        and b.TypeCode not in ('FOO', 'BAR')
    where b.TypeCode < @MaxType
```

Which works most of the time, but in some queries SQL Server decides to convert it to something like this (according to the query plan).

```
select max(TypeCode) TypeCode
    from table1 a
    left join table2 b on b.table1id = a.id
        and b.TypeCode < @MaxType
        and b.TypeCode not in ('FOO', 'BAR')
```

That query obviously produces the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'FOO' to data type int.
```

I tried creating a view of table2 without the 'FOO' and 'BAR' values and joining the view instead but the query plan is still the same.

Do you know of a way to prevent the optimizer from changing the query?

PS: I know the design of the table is not the best but this is a legacy database and I can't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem here is that you are combining character and integer semantics in the same query.

There are three possible solutions that I can think of:

1. Change the `@MaxType` parameter to be a `varchar(9)`.  If you are only comparing against single-digit numbers, alphabetical order is OK.  Otherwise, this won't work.
2. Use a `CASE` or `ISNULL(NULLIF(...))` construct in the `WHERE` statement.  This will work, but it is not sargable and will cause the optimizer to ignore any indexes you have on the type code.  Not great.
3. Created a persisted, computed, nullable integer column (i.e. `TypeCodeID`) and index it separately.  Put the `CASE` as the column's expression.  This will take some extra data/index space, but if you want good performance, that is the best way to go.  Then instead of writing `NOT IN ('Foo', 'Bar')` you can just write the first condition (`TypeCode < @MaxType`) because the rows with `Foo` and `Bar` in the `TypeCode` column will have `NULL` in the new `TypeCodeID` column.

I suppose there is also a fourth answer which is to change your design, and this would be the best idea, if it's possible.  If a column can contain character data then you really shouldn't be trying to perform numerical comparisons.  I have a strong suspicion that the character data exists in this column because it's coming from users and isn't validated/sanitized properly, so it's got garbage values like `N/A` or `Unknown` in there.  If that is the case, your DB really should be enforcing data integrity, that's what a DBMS is for.  I know you say you "can't change it", but I don't think this answer would be complete if I didn't recommend against such dangerous practices.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to turn off the optimizer, and you probably don't really want to anyway.  A better solution is probably to modify the query.

You can probably make this work with a CASE statement -- something like:

```
SELECT MAX(TypeCode) TypeCode
FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table2 b ON b.table1id = a.id
WHERE CASE WHEN b.TypeCode IN ('FOO', 'BAR') THEN 99999999999 ELSE CAST(b.TypeCode AS int) END < @MaxType
```

You'll need to check the performance of this to see if it's acceptable, but it should work.